# How can I filter the emails and URL from a big file to one?

Tags: 16.04, python, email, python3

I have very big files stored in a folder. The files generally contain emails and URLs, on each line.
Say for example

```
gg@example.com
example.com
ssdfghhg
www.example1.com
http://www.example2.com
https://example3.com
better@example123.com
```

I want to know how I can separate out the emails in one file and URLs in a separate file. 
Kindly let me know how Ubuntu version of python can help me doing this?

```
output:  
email.txt
gg@example.com
better@example123.com
URL.txt
example.com
www.example1.com
http://www.example2.com
https://example3.com
```

I am expecting the output file to be UTF-8. just expecting the URLs should be syntactically a URL. No need to verify whether the URL is existing or not.

Comment: One question: should all data of all files land into one single output file, or one output file per file?

Comment: @JacobVlijm All email in one and URL and another. Input should be a directory.

Comment: Hi Jaffer, rereading your question, you might want to add: 1. the lines might include multiple strings (url, email or neither) 2. you did not mention the possible encoding issue. 3. Furthermore, there is actually no way to define `URL.txt` is an invalid url, *without* having a list of invalid or valid domains. The dot is the  only marker, which does not work in this case. Could you clarify in the question, also for @Shreyash S Sarnayak?

Comment: @JacobVlijm ok I will explain.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import glob  # to get all files in a directory
f1 = open('email.txt', 'w')     # Open in write mode
f2 = open('url.txt', 'w')       # Open in write mode

for i in glob.glob(sys.argv[1] + '/*'):
    with open(i) as f:
        for line in f:
            if '@' in line:     # email
                print(line.strip(), file=f1)
            elif '.' in line:   # url
                print(line.strip(), file=f2)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

This works given that your non-URL text doesn't contain `.` in it.

Save it as `file.py` and run it as

```
python3 file.py dirname
```

Comment: If I filter only line with @ then what about if the URL is getting stored in another file. The data might get some garbage too.

Comment: @JafferWilson I did not understand.

Comment: Actually, there might be simple text in a line not always email or URL

Comment: @JafferWilson I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @ShreyashSSarnayak, I am not at home atm, but from chat, I understand the files also possibly have encoding errors. It is not in the question though. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type. Furthermore, '.' Might not be the most reliable marker for a url, better use both `www.` and `http:`/`https:` imo. Also the line might include multiple strings.

Comment: But `example.com` starts with neither with `www.` nor `http:` and you marked it as url. So I used `.` as the marker.

Comment: You are right on that oneI am not Jaffer though :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you 2 are different people.